# Relationship between the constant DATE and getTime() in the Calendar class

Tags: java, constants

I created a program that prints out the time and date of a calendar.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(Calendar.DATE);

        c.set(c.DATE, 1);

        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(Calendar.DATE);
```

**Output:**

```
Fri Nov 28 19:50:10 CET 2014
5
Sat Nov 01 19:50:10 CET 2014
5
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is the initial value of DATE 5?
2. After setting DATE to 1, it remained 5 because it's a constant but c.getTime() returned a different time than before. How 
   does the method know that I set the DATE field to 1 if the variable itself didn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar.DATE` is a static final value that refers to:

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. This is a synonym for DAY_OF_MONTH. The first day of the month has value 1.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE)

It will always be 5, because that's the value that has been assigned to it. [Source of Calendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java)

```
  public final static int DATE = 5; // line 432
```

To get the value you wanted to get, you would do a get, and then use the DATE index, which is 5.

```
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE)); //get the calendar's value of the DATE field.
```

Technically, since we know the DATE key is 5, you could also get away with this (but shouldn't, because bad coding manners!):

```
System.out.println(c.get(5));
```

The reason we don't do that normally is because the static identifier provides clarity.

Answer (score 0):

[`Calendar#DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE) is a `static` field used as the

> number for `get` and `set` indicating the day of the month. This is a
>   synonym for DAY_OF_MONTH. The first day of the month has value 1.

Although you are accessing it as an instance variable here

```
c.DATE
```

it's really a class variable with the value 5.

> Why is the initial value of the DATE field 5?

That is an internal implementation detail.

> When I set DATE to 1, its value does not change but the getTimes()
>   method's output changes. How does the method know that I set the DATE
>   field to 1 if its value didn't change(its value is still 5)?

Again, `DATE` will never change. It is a constant. You're using it to set the date of your `Calendar` object.